# How can I import records from a text file (not delimited) in access db?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, import, records

I am just trying figure out a record import program from text file into access database using Microsoft.Jet.Oledb Provider 4.0 and Vb.net. And it seems easy but my problem is different. In the text file, records are not delimited. I am a newbie so it became too hard for me. Please give some hint to solve this issue.

```
Format of the text file:
Field Name & Size
Date[Date,ShortDate]FirstName[20]LastName[20]Sex[1]Age[2]
Records
02062011john……………..little………………M15
…
…
…
```

Can I put delimiter programmatically while reading the text file using stream reader and later simply import the whole file in DB. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the TextFieldParser class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Private Sub ReadFixedWidthText()
    Dim theString As String = "John                Little              M15" + vbCrLf + "Jane                Doe                 F30"

    Using rdr As New StringReader(theString)
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(rdr)
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth
            parser.FieldWidths = New Integer() {20, 20, 1, 2}
            parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

            While Not parser.EndOfData
                Dim fields() As String = parser.ReadFields()

                For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Length - 1
                    Console.WriteLine("Field {0}: {1}", i, fields(i))
                Next
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I used a StringReader in this example, but you could just as easily use a StreamReader or just use the filename in the TextFieldParser constructor.

Or you could use a combination of the StreamReader and the String.Substring method to get the individual fields.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is like light in dark to me. Once I complete I will post my code here. If anything goes wrong hope i will get help again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not space delimited? Do you have any constraints on text file like for example from first character till 100th character is first name etc? If yes you can break the text on the basis of those constraints.

Comment: I have already given the field sizes. Its like
FirstName (size in character 20), LastName (size in character 20),
Sex(size in character 1), Age (size in character 2)